# how to solve error in test classes( System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0)

Tags: unit-test

Hi I am writing test class for callouts class any one help on this.

```
public class recoverrecords{

public static string response;
public static list<string> first = new List<string>();
public static list<string> last = new List<string>();
public static list<string> com = new List<string>();
public static list<lead> lead = new list<lead>();
public static lead l = new lead();

public static void recover(){

http http = new http();
httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+firstname,+lastname,+company+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True');
request.setMethod('GET');
string Access_Token = userinfo.getsessionid();
request.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+Access_Token);
request.setTimeout(60000);
HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
response=res.getbody();
system.debug('response:'+response);
string firstname;
string lastname;
string company;

JSONParser parser= JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

while (parser.nextToken() != null)
{
if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText() == 'firstname')) {
parser.nextToken();
firstname= parser.gettext()+'\n';
 first.add(firstname);
system.debug('firstname:'+firstname);
}
else if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText() == 'lastname')) {
parser.nextToken();
lastname= parser.gettext()+'\n';
last.add(lastname);
system.debug('lastname:'+lastname);
}
else if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText() == 'company')) {
parser.nextToken();
company= parser.gettext()+'\n';
com.add(company);
system.debug('company:'+company);
}
}
for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    lead.add(new Lead(
            firstname = first[i],
            lastname = last[i],
            company = com[i]
            ));
}
insert lead;
system.debug('lead:'+lead);
}
}
```

HttpCalloutMock class:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        System.assertEquals('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+firstname,+lastname,+company+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
        }
    }
```

test class:

```
@istest
public class testrecoverrecords{

static testmethod void recover(){
 Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
 httpresponse res =new httpresponse();
recoverrecords.recover();
lead l = new lead();
l.firstname = 'p';
l.lastname = 'bics';
l.email = 'hari@bics.com';
insert l;
}

}
```

Comment: In `testrecoverrecords` you may need to create 4 lead records because in class you are using `for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    lead.add(new Lead(
            firstname = first[i],
            lastname = last[i],
            company = com[i]
            ));
}` So firstName lastName list should contains 4 string

Comment: Hi i  added code inserted 4 leads even getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be here:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    lead.add(new Lead(
            firstname = first[i],
            lastname = last[i],
            company = com[i]
            ));
}
```

Here, you are using `first[i]`, `last[i]` and `com[i]`.

In your main class, you are populating these arrays based on the response you get from the webservice callout by parsing the JSON response sent back by the server.
In the case of test class, you have set a mock callout class which is being called when tests are run but they do not return the response expected by the main class.
As your mock response does not have valid JSON response, the JSON parser does not recognize any data and `first`, `last` and `com` arrays are empty.
You can verify this by checking your debug logs.

To solve this, you will need to set the response in the HttpCalloutMock class as follows:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        System.assertEquals('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+firstname,+lastname,+company+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        // HERE YOU NEED TO ADD THE EXPECTED RESPONSE
        // You will have to create the expected response and assign it to following body variable used as parameter for setBody() method
        res.setBody(body);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Here is the link for HttpResponse documentation: [HttpResponse setBody(body)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm#apex_System_HttpResponse_setBody).

Comment: Class.System.JSONParser.nextToken: line 94, column 1
Class.recoverrecords.recover: line 41, column 1
Class.testrecoverrecords.recover: line 7, column 1 these three errors coming while i changed code

Comment: Maybe you have set the JSON body in incorrect format. Can you post the changes that you've made?

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the error message. I can see only line numbers where error occurred.

Comment: i updated my MockHttpResponseGenerator  class with your code and also inserted 4 leads in testrecoverrecords.

Comment: My code is not the correct code. I just showed what needs to be done. The body variable used in setBody() method call needs to have a valid and expected JSON response!

Comment: can u post any example or help me writing MockHttpResponseGenerator

Comment: I don't have any example, but here is what you can do: Add debug statements in your main class to print the response by res.getBody(); method. Use the printed response in your MockHttpResponseGenerator class to set the response of mock callout. @user123

Comment: i added my response what i copy in debug log res.getbody() but its not saved code showing error